# Problem between context and thread in drawRect

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, ios, uiview, drawrect

I'm trying to draw a couple of `UIImage`s in a `UIView`, and I'm doing it by hand with `drawRect:`. Given that the images are dynamically downloaded from the web, I create an `NSOperation` and I perform the image loading code from a second thread, in order to keep UI responsive. So once the images are downloaded, they appear on screen.

But... I get the following errors, for each of the images:

```
<Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextSetBlendMode: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextSetAlpha: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextScaleCTM: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextDrawImage: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0
```

For what I've seen, this means that the context in which I'm trying to make `[image drawInRect...]` is `nil`, because I'm not in `drawRect:` anymore.

Attempted doing

```
UIGraphicsPushContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
```

before drawing the image but nothing changed. How can I overcome this thing? Multithreading is a must for responsiveness, and the context gets lost in the way.

UPDATE: Here's my code:

```
- (void)drawContentView:(CGRect)r
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    ....
    CGContextFillRect(context, r);
    UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
        app.networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;


    NSOperationQueue *queue = [NSOperationQueue new];
    NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc]
                                            initWithTarget:self 
                                            selector:@selector(loadPreview) 
                                            object:nil];
    [queue addOperation:operation];
    [operation release];
}
```

And then

```
-(void)loadPreview
{
    self.preview = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:self.picStringPreview]]];
    [self.preview drawInRect:CGRectMake(256, 18, 80, 65)];
}
```

I tried adding a `UIGraphicsPushContext...` in `loadPreview`, even doing a `[self performSelectorOnMainThread...]` there, and nothing. And this is a custom cell based on Atebit's model, so my cell's superclass makes:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)r
{
    [(ABTableViewCell *)[self superview] drawContentView:r];
}
```

and the code in `drawContentView:` gets draw'd in superclass's `drawRect:`. Any hint?

Comment: Could you post a snippet of the `drawRect:` method? Are you creating the `NSOperation` _inside_ `drawRect:` and then trying to draw the images from that other thread?

Comment: I'm not at home right now, as soon as i get back i'll update my question with snippets. Thanks!

Comment: Just updated post with code snippets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're quite correct about the context being gone by the time you get to drawing the images. UIKit sets up a drawing context for your view before `drawRect:` is called, and it's destroyed afterwards. As a general rule, there will only, and always, be a context set up for you like this in a `draw...` method that you've inherited from a framework class.

So what can you do? It should actually be rather easy. Anomie's answer already told you, in fact. All you need to do is call the draw method on your image back in `drawContentView:` where you know you have a context. In the `loadPreview` method, you call `setNeedsDisplay`*, and in `drawContentView:` you check if `preview` is `nil`, drawing if not. Just to expand on Anomie's answer, here's what the code should look like:

```
-(void)loadPreview
{
    self.preview = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:self.picStringPreview]]];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

---

```
- (void)drawContentView:(CGRect)r
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    ....
    CGContextFillRect(context, r);
    UIImage * prvw = self.preview;    // Avoid making two method calls
    if( prvw ){
        [prvw drawInRect:CGRectMake(256, 18, 80, 65)];
    }
    // etc.
```

You would also probably do well to move the creation and dispatching of the `NSOperation` *out* of the drawing method. It's recommended that all drawing methods do *only* what they need to do and terminate as quickly as possible.

---

*I think Anomie might be wrong about needing to call this through `performSelector:...onMainThread:`, because `setNeedsDisplay` doesn't call `drawRect:` directly, it just sets a flag.

Answer (score 2):

The most straightforward way to do this is not to mess with `drawRect:` at all, and instead put your images in UIImageViews. Apple claims that even an empty `drawRect:` changes something-or-other that makes rendering much slower.

But if you must, you'll have to save the images to ivars in your class (don't forget to retain them), call `setNeedsDisplay` or `setNeedsDisplayInRect:` (on the main thread, so you'll need to use `performSelector:withObject:onMainThread:` if you aren't already) to inform the system that it needs to call your `drawRect:` again, and then when `drawRect:` is called again use the saved images to draw.